# Jquery Remote Validation Rule - php email check failing

Tags: php, jquery, json, validation, jquery-plugins

I have been scanning the interwebs for many days now, and have tried just about everything posted to resolve the issue. What i am trying to do is (like many other posts), send a remote mysql query via remote validation.. there has been much debate on the proper format of the return data (like json_encode or not) and i have tried both suggestions to no avail.

Jquery Code

```
    $('#register-form-step-1').validate({  // initialize plugin
    rules:
    {
        confirmEmail:
        {
            equalTo: "#clientEmailAddress"
        },
        clientPassword:
        {
            rangelength: [6,32],
            required: true
        },
        clientUserName:
        {
            minlength: 4,
            required: true,
            remote:
            {
                async:false,
                type:'POST',
                url:'<?php echo base_url("home/checkusername")?>',
                data: {
                clientUserName: function() {
                return $("#clientUserName").val();
                }},
                success: function(data)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (String(data) === String('true'))
                    {
                        //not registered
                        console.log("Not registered");
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    console.log(data);
                        //already registered
                        console.log("Already registered");
                    }
                },
                error: function()
                {
                    console.log("There was an error");
                }
            }
        },
        clientEmailAddress:
        {
            async:false,
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote:
            {
                type:'POST',
                url:'<?php echo base_url("home/checkemail")?>',
                data: {
                clientEmailAddress: function() {
                return $("#clientEmailAddress").val();
                }},
                success: function(data)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (String(data) === String('true'))
                    {
                        //not registered
                        console.log("Not registered");
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //already registered
                        console.log("already registered");
                    }
                },
                error: function()
                {
                    console.log("There was an error");
                }
            }       
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function ()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo base_url("home/register")?>',
            data: $('#register-form-step-1').serialize(),
            success: function ()
            {
                alert('success')
                console.log('form was submitted');
                $("#register-form-1").modal('hide');
                $("#register-form-2").modal('show');
            },
            error: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                  alert('error')
            }
        });

        return false; // ajax used, block the normal submit
    }
});
```

PHP CODE

```
    public function checkemail()
{

    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['clientEmailAddress']);

    $qResult = $this->db->query('
    SELECT clientEmailAddress FROM clientdata WHERE clientEmailAddress = "'.$email.'" limit 1
    ');

    $result = true;

    if ($qResult->num_rows == 1)
    {
        $result = false;
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($result);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line in **php**

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

by

```
echo json_encode(array($result));
```

and add `datatype` as `json` in `js`

**Otherwise** you can simply try

```
echo 1 or 0; return;
```

Comment: thanks you for the quick response. . I adjusted the code as you suggested, the form is still not valdiating.. no errors are returned as usual.. console shows [true] or [false] now but is does not validate the form

Comment: As you enclosed it in `square brackets` means it is an `array`.Right??? If yes, then `cast` it.

Comment: right.. an array, i wasnt sure how "precise" the reply should be :) i will try to cast the return the data.

Comment: ok ... so the return data is an array .. using jsonParse in the js script should strip out the data.. the part I am stuck on ... the json_encode data is what "validating" the form. so why would casting the array matter at all on the other end "after" it has been validated/not

Comment: Still having issues with this .. was doing some more work on remote and php echo data from json_encode to a jquery handler ... i keep getting UNDEFINED when using any form of parseJSON or just trying to return the object... could this be part of the problem in that the returned json data is empty or being interpreted as invalid?

Answer (score 0):

Before the line :

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Add :

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but finally the sample funtion did it for me.

```
function checkIfEmailExists($email){
    $query="SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='".$email."'";
    $link=@mysql_query($query);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($link);

    $response='';
    if($count==1){
        $response=false;
    }else if($count==0){
        $response=true;
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
    return;
}
```

}